# CSS scrollbar in div doesn't work in FF

Tags: html, css, firefox

The below HTML used to show a vertical scrollbar in FF3.x and IE. I have installed FF6.0.2 and the scrollbar doesn't show up anymore!!

```
<html>
    <body>
        There should be a scroll bar on the page
        <div style="background:red;position: relative; left: -1px; width: 19px; height: 300px; overflow: auto;">
            <div style="background:green;width: 1px; height: 540px;"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

How can I get my scrollbars to appear with latest FF? This still works in IE9. I think this is an issue with the combination of Windows7(Home Premium) and FF6.0.2. I tested this on Windows XP and FF6.0.2 it works fine.

[image]

Comment: It does exactly the same for me in Firefox 6.0.2 as it does in Chrome and Safari, the vertical scroll bar is there in all browsers. See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TKequ/)

Comment: If you zoom out a bit using ctrl+wheel (or whatever) the scrollbar disappears.  Perhaps you are zoomed out slightly?

Comment: No I didn't do anything to zoom setttings. Here is what I see in FF for the link Clive gave in both FF and IE. FF-  http://www.flickr.com/photos/68023709@N08/6186574780/in/photostream   IE - http://www.flickr.com/photos/68023709@N08/6186577542/in/photostream

Comment: BTW if I install customized themes in FF I do see the scrollbar. But that's not what I'm looking for!!

Comment: With the default theme in Firefox 6.0.2 on Mac OS X 10.6.8, there is a scrollbar. You can preview your tests here: http://jsfiddle.net/7VwfK/

Comment: Scrollbars working here. Try ctrl-zero to reset the zooming, or try installing FF again. If all else fails set overflow to scroll in css, if it's still not working try new glasses.

Comment: @Srini Kandula: Please try to re-install your FF browser. Check the question, I've added the image to your question.

Comment: Works in FF for me, too.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your overflow to scroll:

```
overflow:scroll;
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: overflow:auto; is better option to use to display scrollbar when content is overflown. The scrollbar is not shown when the content fits the component size.